# Kendo ui (jquery) DropDownList - do not show selected option in drop down

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, telerik-grid

I want to hide selected item in the drop down.

```
let data = [
      { id: 1, name: "Apples", isDeleted: false},
      { id: 3, name: "Mangoes", isDeleted: false},
      { id: 2, name: "Grapes", isDeleted: false},
      { id: 5, name: "Papaya", isDeleted: false},
      { id: 4, name: "Banana", isDeleted: false}
    ]
  $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: data.filter(item=> item.id != 2),
    dataTextField: "name",
    dataValueField: "id",
    select: function(e){ },
    template: kendo.template($("#template").html())
  });
```

I  tried to remove the item from the data source on select event and directly assign text and value to dropdown. But then value will be empty maybe because the set value does not exist in datasource. couldn't find solution for this in kendo documentation.

```
...
 select: function(e){
      console.log(e);
      e.preventDefault();
      let selectedItemId = e.dataItem.id;
      let selectedItemName = e.dataItem.name;
      e.sender.dataSource.data(data.filter(item => item.id!=2 && item.id != selectedItemId));
      
      e.sender.text(selectedItemName);
      e.sender.value(selectedItemId);
          
      e.sender.value() // this will return empty!!!
 },
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to remove the item from the data source. Just hide whatever is selected. This idea is based on this [article](https://jpllosa.blogspot.com/2021/01/kendo-dropdownlist-example.html).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI DropDownList Example</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.617/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.617/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<input id="dropdownlist" style="width: 400px" />
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField: "name",
            dataValueField: "id",
            dataSource: {
                data: [
                    { id: 1, name: "Apples" },
                    { id: 3, name: "Mangoes" },
                    { id: 2, name: "Grapes" },
                    { id: 5, name: "Papaya" },
                    { id: 4, name: "Banana" }
                ],
                
            },
            open: function(e) {
              var index = e.sender.select();
              var items = e.sender.items();
              for (var a = 0; a < items.length; a++) { 
                $(items[a]).show();
              }
              $(items[index]).hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```